# CSS:Disable :before pseudo when UL without LI sub-elements

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I have a css define as below:

```
ul:before{
    content:'';
    //other css definitions 
}
```

what I want is that, the :before pseudo only works when the UL has LI children, if the UL has no LI,make the :before invisible.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What effect do you want the before pseudo element to produce? (Might it be achievable instead on the first li?).

Comment: What I want is, when there is no LI under UL, the UL(or UL:before) is invisible, otherwise it must be visible.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'invisible'? e.g. not rendered at all or rendered but can't be seen (like opacity: 0) or...

Comment: opacity:0 AND display:none, Both are OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the solution offered by @MrSwed (using :empty)doesn't work for you because of layout you might be able to use a pseudo element on the first li.

It depends on exactly what you want to achieve.

UPDATE: it is required that the UL have a background image if there is at least one LI. This snippet puts a background image onto the before pseudo element of the first LI, but it is sized and positioned in relation to the UL and therefore looks like a background to the whole UL.

```css
ul {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  /* just so it shows for this demo */
}

li:first-child::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0 left: 0
}
```

```html
<h2>Empty ul</h2>
<ul></ul>
<h2>ul with a couple of lis</h2>
<ul>
  <li>first li</li>
  <li>second li</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But my :before pseudo element is for UL,not for LI.

Comment: I understand that, but as a pseudo element is purely visual why does it matter if it can give you the same effect? Could you say what effect you want. For example, the content can appear in the right place or have the right background and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your patient. The UL:before is for background of UL, but in the case the UL has no LI , the :before still show as a small dot, what I want is let the small dot disappear when UL has no children.

Comment: You can make the pseudo element on the first LI into a background for the whole UL - why would that not be OK?

Comment: Because the :before is a background for whole UL element, not only the first LI.

Comment: You can make it look like the background for the whole UL, that is the point of having the UL positioned and not the LI - the pseudo element will take its positioning and sizing from its nearest positioned ancestor.

Comment: I've altered the snippet to put in a background image rather than content.

Comment: But sorry because I am a newbie of SO, I have not enough reputation to make an effective vote for your answer... So sorry.

Comment: If it answers your question then I think you can accept it - the idea being that it will help others find the solution in future. But if it doesn't fully answer it then of course don't accept it! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

if you control html and can out complete empty `ul`, you can use `:empty`

```css
ul:not(:empty):before {
 content:'';
}
```

or

```css
ul:before {
 content:'';
}

ul:empty:before {
 content:none;
 display:none;
}
```

this will work  for

```html
<ul></ul>
<ul><!-- and with comments too --></ul>
```

but will not, if there any visible symbol inside `ul`

```html
<ul>
</ul>
<ul> </ul>
```

Another way, control the output at the initial stage and add a class to the `ul` if it has no childs. And you can use it in css for turn off `: before`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it seems it not work because (maybe) the pseudo element :before is look upon as a UL child element, so even if there is no li under ul,the empty is not work.

Comment: Please note that there should not be any symbols between the tags `<ul>` and `</ul>` - no line breaks or spaces, only in this case `: empty` is triggered

Comment: Yeah,I know that, but it doesn't work, cause the :before here is a child of UL.